# Rails 3.2 double nested form and posting from child (Mongoid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Having trouble posting from a child to a parent's other child:

Can this be done like I want, post from the child (Order) to the Parent's (User's) other child (Customer) or do you have to go at this from some other angle?

I have 3 Models:

```
class User
  has_many :orders
  has_one :customer, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer

class Order
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project

class Customer      
  belongs_to :user
```

I've tried accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders from the user, I've also tried accepts_nested_attributes_for :user from the order

neither seem to work,

Hers my form:

```
= form_for @order do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :user_id
  = f.fields_for :user do |user|
    = user.fields_for :customer do |customer|
      = customer.hidden_field :customer_attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is possible. Anyway you certainly forgot to add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

in your `Order` class.

Comment: I actually tried that and many other variations as mentioned above.